# How to define per-user permissions in fixtures in Django?

Tags: django, django-authentication, user-permissions

I have several models, including `User` and `Group` from `contrib.auth`. I run Django 1.4.1.

None of the users appears to have permissions:

```
In [1]: User.objects.get(id=1).user_permissions.all()
Out[1]: []
```

So, this means user has no permissions, and there are no permissions in the user's group. But

```
In [2]: User.objects.get(id=1).has_perm('change_profile')
Out[2]: True
```

(Expected `False`)

How can have only permssions set explicitly? Do I need to change auth backend for this?

In settings, only model backend is set:

```
In [23]: settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS
Out[23]: ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the user was superuser (`is_superuser`), and any permission check would return True.